# Retrying ExecuteNextAsync on 429 error in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

If a `DocumentClientException` with StatusCode 429 (`RequestRateTooLarge`) occurs when calling `IDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync`, is it safe to call `ExecuteNextAsync` again after a delay? In other words, is it guaranteed that the query will return the correct results on a retry (assuming that no further 429-error is thrown)?

(I am using `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` Version 2.9.2.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to call again after you get a 429. I recommended using Polly and use a retry policy with backoff + jitter with Cosmos or any call you are making over a network to help with these and other transient errors you may encounter.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Do you have an example of working code?